# liberasurecode has deprecating version when install swift-all-in-one

Tags: openstack

I was install openstack swift-all-in-one on my virtual mechine with system Ubuntu Destop 14.04. 
It told me that my liberausercode has deprecating version that I need to upgrade when I excute '$HOME/swift/.unittests' in terminal. But the question is how can I upgrade it.
Here is the response:

> liberasurecode[11645]: liberasurecode_backend_open: dynamic linking error libJerasure.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   ERROR: Failure: MissingSectionHeaderError (File contains no section headers. file: /etc/swift/swift.confg, line: 1 ' cd $HOME/swift/doc; sudo cp -r saio/swift /etc/swift; cd -\n')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
>       addr.filename, addr.module)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 512, in _read
>       raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
>
> MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
>   file: /etc/swift/swift.confg, line: 1
>   ' cd $HOME/swift/doc; sudo cp -r saio/swift /etc/swift; cd -\n'
>
> pyeclib: WARNING: DEPRECATED WARNING: your liberasurecode 1.0.9 will be deprecated in the near future because of the issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/swift/+bug/1639691; Please upgrade to >=1.3.1 and rebuild pyeclib to suppress this message
>   --------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------
>   FAILED (errors=1)
>   /root

Answer (score 1):

On websit : https://github.com/openstack/liberasurecode, I find the answer how to update the library.